# Flask Python : styled checkbox change status from checked to unchecked (and vice versa) - change variable within python

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, flask

I have been building my front end for a home water irrigation system and I have embarked on this journey by the means of Flask.

I am still doubtful about my understanding of callback functions and still have a lot of problems with html, css and how the whole animation works.

So I want to have a simple toggle button which on click:

- changes the variable within python from false to true (if button is false) and save the status of that button in html
- change the variable within python back to false when clicked again

(use case: turning on the motor from the web Visualisation)

The on click shall change the style of the button:

[image: when button not clicked/motor turned off]

I took the styling from:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

And when the motor is activated the button should be like this:

[image: when button clicked/motor turned on]

So far I added within my index.html the following code:

```
                <label class="switch">
                   <form method="post">
                    <input type="submit" name="check" value="True">
                    <input type="submit" name="check" value="False">
                   </form>
                  <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
```

modified from the original implementation in html because check did not work:

```
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
```

the css file to accompany that base_style.css:

```
 /* The switch - the box around the slider */
 .switch {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          width: 60px;
          height: 34px;
          }

       /* Hide default HTML checkbox */
  .switch input {
          opacity: 0;
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          }

 /* The slider */
   .slider {
          position: absolute;
          cursor: pointer;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          background-color: red;
          -webkit-transition: .4s;
          transition: .4s;
      }

   .slider:before {
       position: absolute;
       content: "";
       height: 26px;
       width: 26px;
       left: 4px;
       bottom: 4px;
       background-color: white;
       -webkit-transition: .4s;
       transition: .4s;
     }

     input:checked + .slider {
       background-color: green;
       }

      input:focus + .slider {
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px green;
       }

      input:checked + .slider:before {
       -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
       -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
       transform: translateX(26px);
       }

      /* Rounded sliders */
      .slider.round {
        border-radius: 34px;
       }

     .slider.round:before {
       border-radius: 50%;
       }
```

The python side of the implementation:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def button():
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.form['check'] == "True":
        print("True")
    elif request.form['check'] == "False":
        print("False")
return render_template('index.html')
```

So every time I click on the button, I read in the console the following:

[image: console]

The button doesn't seem to toggle (it's always red) and the variable is just set to true and never to false (I thought that html sets that by itself?)

So the question is: what am I doing wrong? is this possible just using flask, html and css or must I add some library to help me do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want JS and AJAX here rather than a form submission that won't preserve the toggle state easily.

Comment: @ggorlen the issue is I have checked 5000 sources on how to develop front end with python and almost every framework has a scope which is not covered by the other :D it is frustrating a bit. I will look into JS and AJAX then, thanks for the tip